# How are labels on ArrayCollections in forms rendered?

Tags: symfony

I have a `Customer` object, which has many `Emails`.

I'm building a form for my customer, and I've added his emails as a collection. In my template, I render the emails portion like this:

```
<h4>Emails</h4>
{% for email in form.emails %}
  <li>
    {{ form_row(email.addr) }}
    {{ form_row(email.isPrimary) }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
...
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

This works fine, except if the customer has no emails. Then, `form_rest()` renders the label 'emails' at the bottom of my template.

Why does this only get rendered when `form.emails` is empty? How can I customize it? (Note I've already customized my label rendering for other form elements, and I don't want it to be the same for these 'collection labels'.)

Comment: Please paste your form class, entities, and action code.

Comment: I did, they seem to have disappeared. Did someone else delete them or were they not saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solved this problem this way:

```
{% for email in form.emails %}
    {# ... #}
{% else %}
    {{ form_widget(form.emails) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Unless someone suggests a better way of doing this.